# First item custom style border in ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, itemcontainerstyle

How can I set different style for first item in ListView? In my case, I want to change first item border, to get GUI like this:

[image: list with different border for first item]

My current code (no top border):

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simple solution. You don't have to write custom converters etc. Use `PreviousData in RelativeSource`

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger 
                Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,0,1"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: You should also know, that it doesn't work if you gonna resort list